# Hide some functions from display in PG Admin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed modules (XML2, UUID) in Postgres.

In PG Admin III, all the functions contained in those modules display under the "Functions" tree.

The list is lengthy, and it slows down my work since I have to scroll around them quite a bit in my everyday projects.

Is there a way to hide (not display) the functions that are in add-on modules??

Comment: You can also create those functions in a different schema using `create extension ... schema ...` then those functions would not show up in the public schema.

Comment: Thanks Horse.. that's what I did based on your suggestion. Worked great. It moved 23 functions out of the way, out of the main schema. I only had to change a few lines of code to add the schema name to the function calls. Also, it occurred to me that this is just good house keeping by separating core functions from functions I use daily for special projects. If you had this as an answer--I'd check the box.

Answer (score 0):

On the pgAdmin3 [options dialogue](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/options.html), under "[Browser](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/options-browser.html) -> Display", you'll find the various DB object types that you may display/hide in the browser.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. It hides ALL the functions. I'm trying to hide the only the functions of the add-on modules.